# Как в Java создать объект класса, переданного в метод объекта?

Tags: java, объекты

```
public static Map setMap(List<Person> list, Map<Integer, List<Person>> map) {
    for (Person p : list) {
        int year = p.getBirthday().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (map.containsKey(year)) {
            map.get(year).add(p);
        } else {
            map.put(year, new ArrayList<>());
            map.get(year).add(p);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Есть такой метод, если что-то не так, то простите, на Java 3 день.
Метод принимает объекты типов: TreeMap и HashMap (второй явный аргумент). И возвращать должен объект того же класса. 
В данном случае я модифицирую переданный объект, а мне необходимо создать новый, но того же класса, что и переданный, заполнить его и вернуть. Но так как в сигнатуре метода не указано какой именно объект будет передан, то я не понимаю что надо сделать, чтобы узнать создавать объект класса TreeMap или HashMap. 
Как это можно узнать, основываясь только на переданном объекте map?

Comment: Сигнатуру метода можете поменять? Есть красивое решение на дженериках

Comment: Да я думал об этом, но выглядит не очень привлекательно, получается, что я тело метода переношу в отдельный метод и создаю два новых.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо, почитаю про дженерики.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а какая разница. будет вместо Person P стоять. и ничего толком не изменится

Comment: @Санаев Не вместо Person, а вместо Map

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а как это будет выглядеть, можно пример?

Comment: @Санаев Как-то так https://ideone.com/O3DWcR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сама постановка вопроса неправильна. `Map` - это **интерфейс**. Это значит, что реализован он может быть **любым** классом. И того, кто получил экземпляр этого интерфейса не должно вообще интересовать в каком классе содержится реализация данного конкретного объекта

Comment: Я б ещё добавил что метод с именем ´setMap´ не должен возвращать значение, это же имя для сеттера. Но этот метод совсем другое делает.

Comment: И похоже что у метода две задачи: 1) получить копию объекта `Map` и 2) поменять значение в этом объекте по ключу. Может, лучше будет разделить задачи по двум методам?

Answer (score 0):

Например можно поставить дополнительное условие:

```
if (map instanceof TreeMap) {
    // Какие-то действия
} else {
    // Другие действия
}
```

Только учтите, что `instanceof` это дорогая операция, и ее нельзя выполнять слишком часто (тратится много процессорного времени)..

Comment: А если это не сам TreeMap а его наследник?

Answer (score -1):

Для того, чтобы создать объект того же класса вы можете воспользоваться методом `clone()`. Не обязательно привязывать метод к конкретной имплементации `Map` и создавать объект через `new`.

Comment: У него нет объектов. Он работает с интерфейсами. А поддерживает ли данная реализация `Cloneable` - вопрос открытый

Comment: Объекты передаются через интерфейс. Как и у всех объектов в Java есть метод `clone()`, для этого не обязательно имплементировать `Cloneable`.

Comment: А ничего, что этот метод, по умолчанию, protected?

Comment: Если не понимаешь что такое `protected` тo читай руководство по языку.

Comment: Давайте разговаривать кодом. Вот код https://ideone.com/ZSEI7r клонируйте мне там `Map`

Comment: Ты что не понимаешь как клонировать объект? Если у тебя есть другие вопросы то незачем их писать в коментариях к этому ответу.

Comment: Т.е. кода, поясняющего **Ваш** ответ не будет. В чем тогда ценность такого ответа?